# Amulet near Vulgrim

Tags: darksiders

How do I get what looks like a floating amulet near Vulgrim in the Drowned Pass? It's the nearest amulet to Vulgrim and it's in the air but I can't reach it, there's also a chest in front of it but I can't figure out how to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the Abyssal Chain hook hanging in the air. 
[image]

Come back to the area when you have the Abyssal Chain and you can swing across to the chest